# Issue while calculating sum in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have two datasets having two fields each. In a table I have added two fields from one data set and one column from another dataset. I have used Lookup function to add the field from another database. But when I am calculating the Sum of this lookup function by Sum (Lookup(....)) Its giving me blank.

I have also tried the SumLookup() method but its still giving me blank.

Please suggest what needs to be done.

Comment: I don't think that `Sum` works across multiple datasets. My best guess is, you'll have to join the datasets together and calculate the `Sum` this way. But if it really are only 2 values that you're trying to add, you don't to provide datasets for them. You can just pass them as parameters.

Comment: It should work if your lookup is returning the right values. Check if your target dataset has null values.